# A directional word : Can you guess?

Tags: word, wordplay

> I am a directional word with one vowel missing.
>
> I am made up of three consecutive and separate words, each with multiple meanings.

**What word am I?**

Comment: Multiple meanings isn't that restrictive of a clue in English. For example, in "a directional word with one vowel missing", every word except "vowel" has more than one meaning :)

Comment: not sure what you are saying. please explain

Comment: Here is to better understand what @jafe means: consider the word "flow". That is a directional word; it can measure the moving along of liquids (e.g. overflow) or traffic (figure of speech, really) or even hair, etc. i.e., multiple meanings. Now this word doesn't solve the puzzle (I only thought of it because the word "vowel" has "ow" and I thought of the word "fl**ow**", if you are curious), but it is an example to illustrate jafe's point.

Comment: See @Tom's answer. It kind of explains it. It is not my answer though

Comment: @DEEM What I mean is that almost all common words have multiple meanings. "A" can be the letter or an article. "Directional" can be something related to a direction or something giving directions/guidance. "With" can mean "against" (a battle with the Germans) or "using" (a battle with cavalry) etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Second try after first was overturned:

> counterclockwise

with explanations:

> It gives a rotational direction and has no letter a
>  counter ~ go against/adding bead, clock ~ hit/timepiece, wise ~ direction/has wisdom

---

> upsidedown

With explanations:

> It tells of a direction, has no **a**, up ~ above/awake, side ~ edge/team and down ~ below/feathers.

Comment: Great. ONE MORE @Tom

Comment: Also is Upsidedown a single word? It is usually shown as Upside down??

Comment: @DEEM - oh, this answer is usually two words - I will think again :P